# Hide segment of a line in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am. trying to hide a portion of a series. I am using zone to do that, but somehow the `visbile: false` property doesn't work inside a zone. Is there any better way of doing that?

E.g., I am trying to hide the dotted part in the below exmpale:

https://jsfiddle.net/abdfahim/7849x56y/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the custom class for the zones and hide all the lines and points.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }, {
    data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5],
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
      value: 3,
      dashStyle: 'solid',
      className: 'zone-0'
    }, {
      value: 5,
      className: 'zone-1'
    }, {
      dashStyle: 'solid',
      className: 'zone-2'
    }]
  }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-graph.zone-1 {
  display: none;
}

.highcharts-area.zone-1 {
  display: none;
}

.highcharts-point.zone-1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.zones